Crawlee Puppeteer failing to crawl all links on a page when the website is hosted on AWS s3
I'm writing a crawler using apify's crawlee library + puppeteer. This question might be answerable by someone knowledgeable in just AWS / S3. Basically this is used to crawl internal documentation so that it can be made searchable within the company. Due to some security constraints outside of my control, the crawler can't directly access the website that the docs are hosted on. To work around this, I copy them over to an S3 bucket that's on the same VPC and point the crawler at that instead.
This works well enough except I've noticed that it's very finicky about the URL in some cases. This documentation is not just "one website" using the same tech. It's a bunch of different static sites, all hosted on the same server, using different static site generators. For some sites, when I submit a URL to the crawler it has to be formatted EXACTLY like this:
<aws-s3-bucket-domain>/org-name/team-name/branch-name/
If you submit the following, it will crawl the root page, not find any other links and finish:
<aws-s3-bucket-domain>/org-name/team-name/branch-name (no trailing /)
<aws-s3-bucket-domain>/org-name/team-name/branch-name/index.html (.index.html)
Oddly, it does still crawl the root page, it just doesn't find any other links like it does when you submit it with a trailing / i.e
<aws-s3-bucket-domain>/org-name/team-name/branch-name/some_other_page_linked_in_index/
Is this an issue with S3, like an option I need to turn on? Unfortunately I can't control the content of the static sites. It's entirely possible the site generators are handling URLs strangely.
I can include the code of the web crawler if necessary.

#1 Is your issue that url of your website doesn't have the same syntax? #2 Who configured the websites on s3?

#1: I am not sure. I've just observed the the crawler fails to index anything more than the index page when a link is submitted to it with those syntax varieties. I've plugged it (the "bad syntax" url) into my browser and it appears no different. #2 Someone other than me but I / we can change the config. Right now they're all just in one bucket.
